# How do I save a 2D-matrix as (bmp) image such that it looks similar to what image() produces?

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D uint16 matrix where the values range from 0 to 10424. I would like the result to be a saved monochrome image that looks similar to what image() produces (+ different color plate). I tried using imwrite and mat2gray with different bounds and shifting of the values, but failed until now.

What kind of translation does image() do that I would need do manually do that I can call imwrite(matrix, colorplate, file_type) or something similar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the ind2rgb function

```
f = randi([0 10424],500,500); % generate random data
rgbImage = ind2rgb(f, jet(10424)); % apply color
imshow(rgbImage); % display (or use imwrite here)
```

View [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) page for a list of available colormaps (other than jet).